# How to output an array from localStorage?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I save the changes to the array in `localStoage` using the `save()` method. I use it in the `remove()` and `add()` methods, and elements are removed or added to `localStoage`.But when I change the variable `this.Mycollection` which stores my static array in the `getPictures()` method to the variable `this.getCollection` to dynamically display data after adding or deleting elements, the changes occur only after reloading the page. Also, when I clear `localStoage` then I get the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

**I need to implement storing the gallery entries in `localStorage` so that when you reload the page, delete or add all changes are saved.**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {myCollection} from  './gallery-data'; // my static array
import {Picture} from "./gallery-module/gallery/Picture"; // interface

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GalleryService {
    Mycollection: Picture[] = myCollection;
    getCollection = JSON.parse(localStorage["Collection"]);

    constructor() {}

    save() {
        localStorage["Collection"] = JSON.stringify(this.Mycollection);
    }

    getPictures(): Picture[] {
        return (this.Mycollection);
    }

    remove(picId: number): void{
         this.Mycollection = this.Mycollection.filter(p => p.id !== picId);
            this.save();

    }

    add(title: string, url: string): void {
        const id: number = Math.max(0, ...this.Mycollection.map(({id}) => id)) + 1;
        const post: Picture = {
            title,
            url,
            id
        };
        this.Mycollection.unshift(post);
        this.save();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is getCollection? It‘s not used but to take the Collection.

Comment: i use this method in component

Comment: but it’s used like a variable, not like a function.

Comment: ngOnInit() {
        this.collection = this.galleryService.getPictures();
    }

Comment: than i do  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6" *ngFor="let pic of collection">

Comment: getPictures is not getCollection. Please read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you want `getCollection` to be a function that returns the local storage but you actually made it into a member variable that is initialised during the creation of the object (as if it was in the constructor).

Instead of:

```
getCollection = JSON.parse(localStorage["Collection"]);
```

Perhaps you meant to write:

```
getCollection() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage["Collection"] || "null");
}
```

(The `|| "null"` part makes this return `null` if there is no **Collection** property in `localStorage`)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I save changes when deleting or adding items after reloading the page?

Comment: I think, if he has already a getPictures function, he doesn’t need a getCollection function. Just needs MyCollection to be assigned with the value of the parsed Json.

Comment: i changed my func  code to this     getPictures(): Picture[] {
        this.save();
        return JSON.parse(localStorage["Collection"] || "null");
    }

Comment: @IgorShvets Why you save before getting the array? This seems quite confusing. If you’re saving the current state. you don’t have to get it at all. Just use MyCollection.

Answer (score 4):

You got

> Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

because `JSON.parse` called on `undefined` (`localStorage["Collection"]` is empty or not set at all)

Answer (score 2):

If you want MyCollection to be set to the value of localStorage[„Collection“], you should do this:

```
constructor() { 
// I’d rather use functions than string-Properties 
    let collection=localStorage.getItem(“Collection”);
    //Only parse if defined and to Mycollection
    if(collection){
         this.Mycollection=json.parse(collection)||[];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make getter for `Pictures` as:

```
export class GalleryService {
    ...

    get Pictures(): Picture[] {
        return this.Mycollection;
    }

    ...
}
```

then use `Pictures` in your `HTML`. Something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let picture of Pictures">
    <img [src]="picture"/>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean instead "getPictures()"  use get Pictures() ?

Comment: it's not solve my problem, i  need to implement storing the gallery entries in localStorage so that when you reload the page, delete or add all changes are saved.